# How to validly add linux command option at the end?

Tags: linux, shell

I am wondering how I can add linux command option at the end without error.

For example

`rm file1/ -r`

`cp file1/ file2/ -r`

I experience some Linux cluster system can do it, bus others cannot.

As searched for while, getopts command may help but I am not sure if getopts is best choice for that and (also not sure how to implement for that my purpose).

Do I need to customize command by command or there is more general solution that can be applied any command?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you asking how do you implement this in your utility that you are creating? or just can you do this? I'm not entirely sure what the question is here.

Comment: I can't do this with my knowledge, so I just want to know how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this command:

```
rm -f myfile -r -- -i
```

The GNU flag convention is to allow options anywhere, up until an optional `--` to indicate "end of options". Programs following it will see the options `-r` and `-f`, plus the arguments `myfile` and `-i`

The BSD flag convention is that flags are only allowed up until the first non-flag argument, or until an optional `--`. Programs following it will see the option `-f`, plus the arguments `myfile`, `-r`, `--` and `-i`.

POSIX only requires utilities to support the BSD style.

It's up to the individual program to decide how to interpret flags. If you're on a BSD style system like FreeBSD or macOS, you can install GNU tools and use those. If you can't, you're mostly stuck with the system's flag convention.